# How can I use right-aligned text in Typst?

Tags: typst

I'm currently developing my resume at the moment, how can I setup all texts in Typst like in the image down below?

[image: Example Image]

I found the official documentation of alignment but nothing was mentioned, wondering if I can set the text like in the image?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a `grid` or a `table`, but in this case a `table` makes formatting a little easier. I'm also using the `tablex` package because it allows you to format each table cell based on its x/y position, which helps avoid styling each item individually.

Specifically, `set align(right)` in the `format-titles` function right-aligns the left column and the `gutter`s of the table indicate the spacing.

```js
#import "@preview/tablex:0.0.8": tablex

#show heading: it => [
  #box(it)
  #box(width: 1fr, line(length: 100%))
]
#set text(font: "Roboto")

= Skills & Certifications

#let format-titles(cell) = {
  cell.content = if calc.even(cell.x) {
      set text(weight: "bold", size: 1.1em)
      set align(right)
      cell.content
    } else {
      set text(weight: "light")
      cell.content
    }
  cell
}

#tablex(
  columns:2,
  stroke: none,
  inset: 0pt,
  row-gutter: 1em,
  column-gutter: 1em,
  map-cells: format-titles,
)[
  ServiceNow Certification
][
  System admin
][
  General Programming Knowledge
][
  Git, Linux, CLI
][
  Frontend Development
][
  HTML5, Javascript, CSS
]
```

[image]

Comment: Just want to add that using the tablex package is necessary with Typst version 0.10. Native support for per-cell table customization has been merged into the Typst codebase in the meanwhile, so with the next Typst version 0.11+ it shouldn't be needed anymore.

Comment: Glad it's helpful for you! If it addresses your question, can you mark this answer as "correct"?